# File path from user input as get_fields file input in Shiny App

Tags: r, pdf, shiny, shinyapps

I'm building a little applet that will run locally, where people can upload a csv and a fillable pdf and the tool will execute a loop that will fill out the pdfs with names from the csv and save them as png files in an /output directory.

I am having trouble with the pdf portion. Using shinyFiles they navigate to the pdf and get its path, but am getting an invalid path error trying to get the pdf fields (staplr). I think it is happening with `get_fields` but I can't think of another way to get the pdf location.

Warning: Error in path.expand: invalid 'path' argument
[No stack trace available]

Code snip below. Any ideas welcome!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(staplr)
library(DT)
library(shinyFiles)
library(pdftools)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("Award PDF Creation App", style = "color:#3474A7")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Award Creation Tool"),
      
      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),
      
      fileInput(inputId = "filedata",
                label = "Choose your CSV file",
                accept = c(".csv")),
      
      shinyFilesButton("pdf", "PDF select", "Please select a PDF", multiple = TRUE, viewtype = "detail"),
      tags$p(),
      tags$p('Please choose the fillable PDF for award creation.'),
      tags$hr()
      
    ),
    mainPanel(h3("Review your CSV format before you Create PDFs"),
              DTOutput(outputId = "table"), 
              tableOutput("contents"),
              actionButton("go", "Create PDFs") 
              )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  
  volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())
  shinyFileChoose(input, "pdf", roots = volumes, session = session,
                  filetypes = c('', 'pdf'))
  # by setting `allowDirCreate = FALSE` a user will not be able to create a new directory
  
  pdf <- reactive(input$pdf)

  data <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath)
  })
  
  pdfpath <- reactive({
    req(input$pdf)
    as.character(parseFilePaths(volumes,pdf())$datapath)
  })
  
  output$table <- renderDT(
    data()
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$go,{
    req(input$filedata)
    req(input$pdf)
    data <- data()
    pdffields <-get_fields(input_filepath = pdfpath, convert_field_names = F)
    
    withProgress(message = 'Making PDFs', value = 0, {
      for(i in 1:nrow(data)){
        pdffields$`Date`$value <- paste(format(data$AWARD_DATE[i], "%B %d, %Y"))
        pdffields$`First Name Last Name`$value <- paste0(data$FIRST_NAME[i], " ", data$LAST_NAME[i])
        filename <- paste0('./output/', Sys.Date(),
                         '_', data$LAST_NAME[i],
                         '_', data$AWARD[i], '.png')
        set_fields(pdf, filename, pdffields)

        bitmap <- pdf_render_page(filename, page = 1, dpi = 300)
        png::writePNG(bitmap, filename)
        
        # Increment the progress bar, and update the detail text.
        incProgress(1/nrow(data), detail = paste("Processing"))
        
        # Pause
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
      }
    })
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: `pdfpath` is a `reactive` so I think you should write `input_filepath = pdfpath()`

Comment: Your question and your code are over-complicated. You should break them down and debug each piece on their own. For example, you don't need to use shiny to make the pdf filling function work

Comment: thanks for the advice. This is the work up from making the pdf fields fill and save, which I can get to work no problem. The person who will use this isn't comfortable in R thus the idea for the shinyapp. 
using ```input_filepath = pdfpath()``` I still get the path argument error